# Best way to get informed of new questions on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

What is your preferred way to get informed of new interesting questions on Stack Overflow? Do you use RSS feeds? Do you keep an eye on your "interesting tags"? Are there other alternatives?

I'm new to Stack Overflow and I'm wondering all the time why I am getting answers to my questions so quickly.

Answer (score 3):

I use Firefox with [Efficient Autorefresh](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/20226) for [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/es-ES/firefox/addon/748), then I leave a browser window open with the "recent questions" page in one corner of my screen.

Answer (score 2):

My finger is glued to the <kbd>F5</kbd> key.